# How to state the contrapositive of English Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the statement,

> : If tomorrow is Friday, then today is Thursday.

State the,

1. Contrapositive

That is the question I got. How to do that

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: State= write,say,express,type,etc.

Comment: If today is not Thursday then tommorrow is not friday.

Comment: This is definitely an English Language Learning question - See the third (verb) definition via [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=definition%20state). $$$$ state (verb): express something definitely or clearly in speech or writing.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ian I got it look at my question now.

Comment: You've replaced it with a new question. Far better to start a new question so all the old comments/answers don't seem out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The original question asked what "state" meant in the phrase "state the contrapositive".  This was my answer:

It means "Write down the contrapositive of this statement."  You should write: "If today is not Thursday, then tomorrow is not Friday."